# How do I solve $\; 3^{2x+1}-10\cdot 3^x+3=0 \quad?$

Tags: logarithms, roots, exponential-function

> Solve the following equation for $x$ : $ \quad3^{2x+1}-10\cdot 3^x+3=0 $

I am baffled to solve this equation. With graphing I have found the answers to be x=1 and x=-1. I would like to know **how** to solve this equation though.

I have tried many different approaches including rearranging to these various forms (in no particular order):

$$3^{2x+1} - 3^{x+2} - 3^x + 3 = 0$$ $$ 3^{2x+1}\cdot(1-10\cdot 3^{-x-1}+3^{-2x}) = 0 $$ $$ -2x  = 10\cdot 3^{-x-1}-3^0 $$

This equation has a term eliminated in it already.

The last equation written is the closest I have gotten to finding the answer, but I don't know how to proceed any further.

Comment: Start by noting $3^{2x+1}=3\cdot(3^x)^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $y = 3^x$, you will get the quadratic equation $3y^2-10y+3=0$.